# Imprimir um caractere no lugar de um número

Tags: c, array, string, caracteres

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[50];
    int i, l = 0;

    printf(" We will count the number of letters\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Tell me the word: \n");
    scanf("%s", str);

    for( i= 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
        l++;
        printf("The letter %d is %d\n", i, str[i]); /* não entendi por que é
        mostrado o valor de cada letra mas não a letra em si */
    }
    printf("|The number of words is: %d\n", l);
    return 0;

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é uma atividade que achei na internet onde eu tenho que achar o tamanho de uma string sem usar a função library.
o que eu não entendi está como comentario no código.
gostaria de saber também por que quando eu coloco "\0" ao invés de '\0' o programa não funciona: entra em um loop infinito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está mostrando o valor numérico e não o caractere porque é isso que mandou fazer. O `%d` manda pegar um valor e imprimir como um número decimal. Se usar `%c` está mandando imprimir o mesmo valor como um caractere. O [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) é uma forma de apresentação, você diz como quer que os valores sejam apresentados. Tem que escolher o formato adequado para sua necessidade.

C é uma linguagem fracamente tipada, então você pode acessar um valor da forma que quiser.

`"\0"` é uma *string*, `'\0'` é uma caractere. Você deve comparar um caractere com outro caractere, não pode comparar com *string* que na verdade é uma sequência de caracteres terminada com um nulo, ou seja, `\0`, portanto `"\0"` na verdade são dois caracteres é o `\0` que está dentro das aspas mais um outro `\0` que é o terminador da *string*, o que na verdade nem faz sentido ter, já que o primeiro terminador já encerra a *string*, mesmo assim amos são colocados ali, por uma questão de coerência.

O que essa condição está fazendo é justamente procurando pelo **caractere** terminador para saber que a *string* acabou. Ao contrário do que pode imaginar a *string* não tem 50 caracteres, ele tem tantos caracteres até encontrar o terminador. Pode acabar antes dos 50, ou depois, o que pegará um espaço de memória não reservado e provavelmente trará problemas. Entenda que se não quiser estourar o espaço reservado, sua *string* poderá ter no máximo 49 caracteres válidos, já que o último será reservado para o terminador.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char str[50];
    printf(" We will count the number of letters\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Tell me the word: \n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    int i;
    for (i= 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) printf("The letter %d is %c\n", i, str[i]);
    printf("|The number of words is: %d\n", i);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pUkLE7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/huyfvdgx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CountWords.c).

Answer (score 4):

Uma string é nada mais que uma cadeia de caracteres, no C, isso significa um array de 'chars' basicamente e no final é acrescentado o caractere '\0'. Note que ele escaneia a entrada e coloca em um array de chars de 50 posições, onde as primeiras serão preenchidas com a palavras escrita + \0 para indicar o final da string e o resto das posições são preenchidos com valores lixos, esse é o motivo de ter o '\0'.

suponha que a entrada seja "Teste"

str[0] = 'T';
str[1] = 'e';
str[2] = 's';
str[3] = 't';
str[4] = 'e';
str[5] = '\0';
str[6] = lixo;
.
.
.
str[49] = lixo;

A uma diferença entre usar aspas duplas e aspas simples. Aspas simples significa que é um char enquanto aspas duplas que é uma string. Um char tem um valor numerico associado a letra, isso está na tabela ASCII, se você usar o %d ele irá printar o valor numérico, o correto é trocar por %c ou %s.

```
printf("The letter %d is %c\n", i, str[i]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Por que dentro do printf(), o seu **segundo %d está errado**. **%d é só para imprimir numeros.**

**%c é para imprimir caracteres; e**

**%s é para imprimir cadeia de caracteres(strings).**

Então o correto seria: (não compilei)

```
printf("The letter %d is %c\n", i, str[i]);
```

Você estava imprimindo a tabela ASCII relativa daqueles caracteres.