# Palavra com ordem inversa

Tags: c, array, for

Estou fazendo um exercício onde tenho que fazer a palavra dada com *input* sair em ordem inversa.

Eu começo contando o numero de letras que tem na palavra digitada (comentado no código). Depois de ter contado o número de letras na palavra eu passo esse valor(quantidade de letras) para um outro *loop* que irá mostrar a palavra na ordem inversa. Por exemplo: se a palavra for **"teste"** eu terei **l = 5**, passando o valor de L para I, a ordem do *print* no *loop* seria *subscript* 5 do array `name`, depois o 4, depois 3... mas isso não está funcionando.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int i, l = 0;
char name[50];
printf("Tell me a word: \n");
scanf("%s", name);
for( i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++){  /* até aqui o código irá simplesmente 
contar o number de letras na palavra digitada*/
l++;
}
if(name[i] == '\0'){
printf("The number of letters is %d\n", l); /* o programa só funciona até
aqui*/
}
printf("The word is the reverse order is\n"); 

for( i = l; i != 0; i--){
printf("%d", name[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seria bom clicar em [edit] e acrescentar sua dúvida na pergunta antes do código. No meio dos comentários fica até difícil de notar. E compensa explicar um pouco melhor, para que fique mais fácil do pessoal ajudar.

Comment: Tente explicar o problema. Dê uma lida em [ask], visite o [tour] e a [help] se for necessário. Siga a dica do Bacco e tente [edit] a pergunta para explicar a sua dúvida, da forma atual, fica difícil de entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem dois erros: parece que não entendeu o que foi respondido na [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172952/101) que precisa usar o `%c` para mostrar caracteres; e ele deve considerar a posição 0 como um dos caracteres a serem impressos, então tem que usar o operador `>=` e não `!=`. Aproveito para simplificar e organizar o código.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char name[50];
    printf("Tell me a word: \n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++);
    if (name[i] == '\0') printf("The number of letters is %d\n", i);
    printf("The word is the reverse order is\n");
    for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) printf("%c", name[j]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s717gF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ttcwipce-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ReverseWords.c).

Comment: Valeu! desculpa, eu entendi a necessidade de usar o %c, é erro viciado, mas obrigado de novo!